# Preterito imperfecto and condicional in reported speech

Tags: pretérito, objetos-indirectos, pretérito-imperfecto, condicional

What is the difference in using those tempos in reported speech apart from representing the future in the past?

1. Dijo que compraba el perro
2. Dijo que compraría el perro

Comment: I guess you wanted to write *perro* instead of *pero* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In spanish the first tends to be used when the speaker you are reffering is decided to do it, while the second one is conditioned and he/she won't do it due to something.

Maybe with the verb comprar in this example we cannot apply the general rule from *Presente* to *Pretérito Imperfecto del indicativo* except if we specify when because the verb itself only takes place for a short time.

But for a recurrent action we can say:

John te dice:

- Canto/Compro muy bien (*I sing so well*)

Un día despues le dices a Maria:

- (John) Dijo que cantaba/compraba muy bien (*He said that He was good at singing/buying*)

The second option can match with the conditionals:

John te dice:

- Compraría el coche, pero no tengo dinero or Compraría el coche si tuviera dinero (*I would buy the car but.../if I...*)

Un día despues le dices a Maria:

- (John) Dijo que compraría el coche , pero no tenía dinero or (John) Dijo que compraría el coche si tuviera dinero (*He said he would buy the car but.../if he...*)

I was trying to make a better answer with more examples but the differences between English and Spanish about these report speech (estilos indirectos) and uses of present/past are a bit different.

Comment: I used just a random verb. I've taken a note in a book that in addition to complex conditional sentence completed with "si tuviera" it was used as is from my example without it

Answer (score 2):

First things first: 
By "pero" you mean "perro" , am i right?. :-)

1) Means he was doing that while talking. Sound to me like: Dijo que estaba comprando... (He/she said he was buying the dog). At the same moment of talking.

2) Means that he/she would buy the dog in the future from the moment of the conversation, but... we still don't know if he really did it. It means like a "promise".

Anyway, the first sentence is a little weird.

Comment: both sentences are from the reported speech in correct usage

Comment: I agree, the first sentence is odd because it translates to "He said he was buying the dog"... indicating that something else occurred during the action.  "He said he was buying the dog when....something happened."  `Él dijo que compró el perro` is very definitive and the timeline is terminated.. the has been bought.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is quite subtle. In the first case, you are pretty confident that the person will do as she said, while in the second case you are not so confident. The conditional always expresses a possibility and not a certainty.

1. María dijo que compraba el perro --> María said that she was buying the dog and you have no reason to believe that she did not do as she said.
2. María dijo que compraría el perro --> María said that she was buying the dog but, for whatever reason, you thing that she might not have done so.

Comment: I see the difference is related to the future tenses in English. will: possibility; going to: planned action; is taking: definite process

Comment: I will buy the dog

Comment: I'm going to buy the dog

Comment: I'm buying the dog

Comment: I will be buying the dog

Answer (score 0):

As you say, one (*compraría*) is representing the future.  The other (*compraba*) could be *either* reporting an action in the imperfect past (concurrent with when "dijo" happens) or the present.  Reported speech has the following "translations" if you will.

- **presente → pret. imperfecto**

  - «*Estudio* español»
  - Me dijo que *estudiaba* español.
- **pret. perfecto → pluscuamperfecto / antepretérito**

  - «*Estudié* español»
  - Me dijo que *había estudiado / estudiara / hubo estudiado* español.
- **pret. imperfecto → pret. imperfecto / pluscuamperfecto prog.** (latter prevents simultaneous interpretation)

  - «*Estudiaba* español»
  - Me dijo que *estudiaba* / *había estado estudiando* español.
- **pluscuamperfecto → pluscuamperfecto**

  - «*Había estudiado* español»
  - Me dijo que *había estudiado* español.
- **futuro → condicional**

  - «*Estudiaré* español»
  - Me dijo que *estudiaría* español.
- **condicional → condicional**

  - «*Estudiaría español*»
  - Me dijo que *estudiaría* español.

All of these are based on two rules if you want to figure out other ones.  Present shifts to imperfect, and imperfect stays in imperfect.  How do you get *pretérito perfecto* to *pluscuamperfecto*?  *estudié* and *he estudiado* are equivalents.  *he* is *presente*, so it shifts to *había* resulting in *había estudiado* from either *estudié* or *he estudiado*.  *Futuro* can be either *estudiaré* or *voy a estudiar*, the latter being *presente* is recast as *iba a estudiar* which is equivalent to the *condicional*.  *Condicional* recasts into *condicional* because it's really *iba a estudiar* which, being imperfect, stays *iba a estudiar*.

Probably more detail than you needed, but should help to understand the why of the answer.